# Problem after updating to latest kotlin version

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, version

I updated my `kotlin version` to `1.4.20` in project build.gradle file in Android Studio. But, i am not able sync my project. I am getting this error:

```
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'Modules'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.4.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:1.4.20).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable/1.4.20/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.4.20.jar
   > Could not find kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.4.20).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.4.20/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.4.20.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I also went to Tools->Kotlin->Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates and installed the latest kotlin. Still i am getting this error.
So, What could be the reason?

**build.gradle (Modules)**

```
    buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.4.20"
        gradleVersion = '4.0.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${gradleVersion}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/local-aar.gradle"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:${gmsLibVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

//Rest of the code
```

Comment: Show your gradle files (project, app, and other if exist)

Comment: added the beginning of two build.gradle files @Metrier

Comment: Able to download the file from JCenter via curl - ` curl -O -vv https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable/1.4.20/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.4.20.jar `. Maybe it's a configuration issue